# When do Tealium vendor tags fire on React pages?

Tags: reactjs, tealium

We've implemented Tealium throughout our site, including some newer, single page app (SPA) content. Our devs are new to Tealium, so we're all kind of building the car as we drive it.

I've read Tealium's docs on both single page apps and the standard order of operations. **What I don't fully understand is when vendor tags fire on SPA sections.** For example, when I first land on a SPA page, I see the HTTP requests indicating the tags have fired (We haven't disabled the initial page view event yet). But as I navigate around that app, triggering the manual link/view events that the devs implemented in the site code, I see those events being logged but the HTTP requests from vendor tags are inconsistent or not-existent. For example, we have a Google Ads tag that appears to fire with each of these events, but we also have  Microsoft Ads tag that does not, despite both tags' Load Rules being configured to load on all pages.

**Can anyone confirm whether utag.view() and utag.link() fire vendor tags when called?** If I'm misunderstanding a piece of the implementation, I'd be grateful for a clarification. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, Tealium knows nothing about your app's events. Like most tag managers, it'll default to firing off a `utag.view()` indicating a new pageview once the page has loaded, but in an SPA app, that happens once and it's got no hook into your router to understand future navigations.

Rather, it's on you to instrument your SPA and augment the router so that when a new route is successfully rendered, you call a `utag.view()` and when other actions occur that you want to track, you make the appropriate `utag.link()` calls as Tealium will not do this for you.